Small Ants on outside of car, where are they nesting?
For a couple weeks there have been small ants all over the outside of my Subaru sedan. It is six years old and I have owned it for 4 years. There are none inside, or in the trunk or under the hood, and not in the air intake / filter area. I drive it several times a week. It is always parked outdoors on pavement or in a parking structure at work.
I took it to a car wash the other day, but today the ants are still there. They disappear when it is hot or in the sun and reappear later. I can't imagine what they are surviving on. Could it have anything to do with antifreeze? (It contains propylene glycol, a food ingredient.) Any ideas where to look or what to do?
Update: there are still a fair number wandering around when it is cool. They have gotten water from recent rain, but I don't know what they might be eating. Hopefully nothing that is part of the car!
Further Update: I bought some ant killing gel and squirted little blobs in corners of the windshield and rear window (exterior) because I didn't want to put it on the paint. Hopefully this will remove them, although they are still not inside and I don't know where they are staying. It's rather hot outdoors on a car sitting in the sun and driving occasionally. Clever bugs.

If you get a lot of insects squashed on the front of your car, they could have been eating those, I suppose. Free radiator cleaning!

@AndrewMorton Subarus never hit any bugs :-)

The ants appear to have been nesting in a body panel behind the front wheel, getting in under a trim piece at the corner of the windshield. That's the area I saw them the most.
I used some gel ant bait / poison on the windshield lower corners (I didn't want to put it on paint or plastic) and eventually all the ants were gone. I used the same stuff inside the house when they showed up there too.
So that took care of the 'problem' eventually, but the bigger questions of where exactly they were nesting and what they lived on, and whether they would have eventually caused damage or a malfunction remain. Recently I had ants move in to a junction box outside, so many that when I turned the light on it blinked on and off a few times. They move up away from the ground in to areas protected from rain and attack.
